# Ruby CSV.readline convert to hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, file, csv

I have file of results of football matches

```
Boca 3, River 3
Independiente 1, San Lorenzo 0
Boca 1, San Lorenzo 1
Independiente 3, River 1
Boca 4, Grouches 0
```

I did:

```
require 'csv'
matches = []
File.readlines('data.txt').each do |line|
    matches << line.chomp
end
puts matches
```

And I need to calculate the result of each match

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: `require 'csv'` is redundant, the code below never uses CSV.

Comment: I don't see where you try to do a calculation. Show us your attempt. Or do you want us to write that for you?

Comment: The first step was to obtain a hash. Now i must calculate the points per match.

Comment: 1. Boca, 6 pts
2. River, 5 pts
3. San Lorenzo, 1 pt
3. Independiente, 1 pt
5. Grouches, 0 pts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
matches = []

File.readlines('data.txt').each do |line|

  my_line = line.chomp.split(', ').map! { |l| l.split(/\s+(?=\d+$)/) }.flatten 

  matches << [['player1', 'scope_p1', 'player2', 'score_p2'], my_line].transpose.to_h

end

p matches
```

[Example Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSwDo.png)

Comment: undefined method `split' for Array

Comment: Please take the time to format the answer correctly for readability. Also, don't use links to images to display important information. Instead, copy that information into the answer. Links rot then break, and when they do that information is lost.

Comment: #=> [{"player1"=>"Boca", "scope_p1"=>"3", "player2"=>"River", "score_p2"=>"3"}, {"player1"=>"Independiente", "scope_p1"=>"1", "player2"=>"San Lorenzo", "score_p2"=>"0"}, {"player1"=>"Boca", "scope_p1"=>"1", "player2"=>"San Lorenzo", "score_p2"=>"1"}, {"player1"=>"Independiente", "scope_p1"=>"3", "player2"=>"River", "score_p2"=>"1"}, {"player1"=>"Boca", "scope_p1"=>"4", "player2"=>"Grouches", "score_p2"=>"0"}]

Answer (score 0):

```
File.readlines('data.txt')
    .map { |e| e.split(", ").map { |e| e.split(/\s+(?=\d+$)/) } }
    .map { |((t1, s1), (t2, s2))| "#{t1}—#{t2} #{s1}:#{s2}"  } 
#=> [
#  [0] "Boca—River 3:3",
#  [1] "Independiente—San Lorenzo 1:0",
#  [2] "Boca—San Lorenzo 1:1",
#  [3] "Independiente—River 3:1",
#  [4] "Boca—Grouches 4:0"
# ]
```

Comment: #=> Boca 3—River 3
 :
Independiente 1—San Lorenzo 0
 :
Boca 1—San Lorenzo 1
 :
Independiente 3—River 1
 :
Boca 4—Grouches 0
 :

Comment: line = line.map { |e| e.split(", ")}
=> [["Boca 3", "River 3\n"], ["Independiente 1", "San Lorenzo 0\n"], ["Boca 1", "San Lorenzo 1\n"], ["Independiente 3", "River 1\n"], ["Boca 4", "Grouches 0\n"]]